# How to manually import Activity Result Contract APIs into my project?

Tags: java, androidx, registerforactivityresult

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA6ms.jpg)So I have created an app (using java) that needs to fetch a text document from storage but the namespace ActivityResultContracts does not seem to be part of the package..

I am using:

**Android Studio Chipmunk,**

**Gradle version 7.3.3**

**Androidx 6.3.1**

I know they are not the latest versions but I was expecting positive results since they are newer than the ones in tutorials and documentations

Is there any way I can manually import the Activity Result Contracts API?

I was expecting to find the ActivityResultContract namespace when I declare the ActivityResultLauncher`Intent`